# Regex to repair linebreaks of Google Calendar ICAL export

Tags: php, regex, google-calendar-api, line-breaks, icalendar

I have been very unlucky in trying to repair Google Calendar's ICAL export. The problem is that a long description (field DESCRIPTION) will have a linebreak containing these characters:

```
[FIRST LINE] 0d 0a 20 [SECOND LINE]
```

So that's a Carriage Return \r, a New Line \n and a simple space.
I'm doing this in PHP's preg_replace - why does this one not work?

```
$text = preg_replace('/\r\n\s/', '', $text);
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The above regex works fine; the problem was somewhere else. Background: This is some wordpress plugin that imports ICAL files. While reading the ICAL file some parsing simply removed all newlines. So this is a layer 8 issue on my behalf. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I'm just guessing, but you probably need to use 'multi-line mode', since the `\r\n` marks the end of a line, and the space won't be matched. I don't know PHP so I can't show you how to do it.

Comment: echo strlen(preg_replace('/\r\n\s/', '', "a\r\n b")); outputs 2 ... seems to work for me. Are you sure your data has this format ?

Comment: @alan: tried /m, but didn't work either.

Comment: @Christoph: the ical file definitly. but this is a good point. let me check if something happened to string right before this parsing.

Comment: You must get rid of the `20` ? Could you try `'/(\r\n?|\n\r?)\s*/'` ?

Comment: @Christoph: confirmed, i stripped it down to /\n\s/ which also doesn't work.

Comment: @SswaterShi: tried, no luck. Something is wrong with the space detection, because a single /\n/ parsing works. crazy: /(\n?)\s*/ will remove _all_ spaces (even single ones)!

Comment: @squeakingsneaker /(\n?)\s*/ will not only match any space character but even nothing (the space between each character) ! To match only more than 1 space you will need /(\n?)\s\s+/ or /(\n?)\s{2,}/

Comment: @all: no wait, there is indeed some sort of trimming being applied at some point.. still looking. Thanks guys for pushing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, you are not *repairing* google iCalendar export but rather just dealing with iCalendar line folding. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1

There are other funkiness of iCalendar that you are likely to face at some point. For example, have a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.11

In other words, you may want to look at existing iCalendar libraries as an alternative to doing the parsing yourself.